# How to change the name of an object placed inside the [FromBody] attribute?

Tags: c#, object, asp.net-web-api, frombodyattribute

I have the class `NameModel` that will be used in the `[FromBody]` attribute. I NEED/am required to use Psswd instead of using the word "Password". `[JsonProperty]` attribute only works when serialized but it doesn't work if users use "Password" as the parameter inside the Body.

The problem is that I want the parameter being used to still be "Password" when placed in the body. Is this possible?

```
public class NameModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Password")]
    public string Psswd { get; set; }
}
```

This is inside my ApiController:

```
public object Login([FromBody]NameModel nameModel) {}
```

Comment: And if you just remove the `FromBody` attribute?

Comment: It still doesn't work. It still can't recognize the word 'Pssd' as 'Password' from the body. So when I retrieve its value it is null.

Comment: Have you tried using DataMember attribute: [DataMember(Name = "Password")] public string Psswd { get; set; } ?

Comment: Yes. I also tried  [Display(Name = "Password")] but still has the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `[FromBody]` and also including

`[JsonProperty("Password")]
public string Psswd { get; set; }`

instead of:

`[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Password")]
public string Psswd { get; set; }`

When I removed `PropertyName =` in the JsonProperty attribute it worked fine for me.